# Spring bean context refresh failing

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to execute below code and getting some error.

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(AspectConfig.class);
        try{
            ctx.refresh();
        }catch(Exception e){
            ctx.close();
            throw new RuntimeException("Bean refresh failed with exception:" + e.getMessage());
        }
```

My `AspectConfig.java` looks like

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"ac","ab","az"})
public class AspectConfig {
     public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
            configurer.enable();
        }
}
```

So the main thing here is I am using spring mvc call to call the code snippet. My spring `WebServletConfiguration` is as follows

```
@Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext ctx) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext webCtx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        webCtx.register(AppConfig.class);
        webCtx.setServletContext(ctx);
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = ctx.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(webCtx));
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/");
    }
```

And my `AppConfig` is nearly the same as `AspectConfig` except that it contains definition for `ViewResolver`.

The error is

```
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-2" java.lang.RuntimeException: Bean refresh failed with exception:Error creating bean with name 'resourceHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
    at framework.AnnotationProcessor.process(AnnotationProcessor.java:40)
    at runners.MultiTestRunnable.run(MultiTestRunnable.java:29)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have had a look at the links below but none seems to be working out. Is it that I cannot use the `AnnotationContext` with `Springs MVC`

Below are the links I had a look

[Spring 5.0.0.M3 Error calling ApplicationEventListener : No ServletContext set - Exception encountered during context initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45944388/spring-5-0-0-m3-error-calling-applicationeventlistener-no-servletcontext-set)

[Error creating bean with name 'resourceHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46548056/error-creating-bean-with-name-resourcehandlermapping-defined-in-class-path-res)

Comment: Can we get a look at hte stack trace ?

Comment: @YassineBadache : I have updated the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to have two separate contexts?
Can you add the `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` annotation in the `AppConfig` class and try?

Or else if you need to have separate web and root contexts then I suggest that you try out `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` class for configuration, this can serve as a replacement for your `WebServletConfiguration` class.
Please refer the [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-servlet-context-hierarchy) for more details.

Comment: Also, you have to use "AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext" in this case as this is a web application. I don't think AnnotationConfigApplicationContext would be useful in this case.